# How do I query for documents that have a blank list?

Tags: mongodb, database

```
db.users.find({'friends':[]});
```

This doesn't work!  I want documents that do not have anyone in "friends" attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
db.users.find({'friends': {$size : 0}});
```

You can read about it here:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24size

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easy using [$size](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24size) operator:

```
db.users.find({'friends': { $size: 0 }});
```